# AngularJS ng-repeat Directive is render all items in browser when any single item is get updated?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

What if my colletion has 5000 records and I'm just updating one records from it, it will be render all 5000 entries again on browser?

```
ng-repeat="item in ctrl.employeeData"
```

After getting single record updates, it takes 2 to 5 second for render those items in browser.

**Is ng-repeat will render everything from scratch?**

please suggest me some solution.

**I don't want to use pagination or lazy loading. Want whole records at a time**

Comment: I don't see any other solution to this problem as long as you want to keep updating single records and deny lazing loading or pagination. Are you transforming your data somehow? If so, this might be a point you can improve (performance-wise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally it renders everything again. To prevent it and to increase your performance you should use `track by` which explicitly keeps track of a property of your choice. This **requires** your data to have an **unique** field to match against. By default angular will use the `$$hashKey` property that gets to attached by angular's `ngRepeat` automatically.

here your can find more info
http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/

Comment: Remember that `track by` requires an unique field in your data. If that's the case, good solution!

Comment: of course. thank you @PhilippMeissner for the completion

Comment: thanks guys! I have added `track by` in ng-repeat so, performance has increased so much. now its really wow effect